# How to test the significance of, and report, a bootstrap of a GLM?

Tags: statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, bootstrap, regression-coefficients

So I'm looking at the number of lion-livestock predation incidents in one area. I created a loop which extracts 390 lion attack days and 390 random non-attack days from 2 data sets to see how climatic variables affect attacks. Obviously each time I run a binomial GLM I get different results based on the different non-attack days. So, I  created a bootstrap to run a binomial GLM 1000 times and extract the associated T-values and coefficient distributions for my independent variables.

I can plot these to look at their significance. But is there any simple way to test and report the significance of my 1000 GLMs, and all the 1000 t values and coefficient distributions for my variables?

Cheers!

Comment: Why do you want to randomly select non-attack days?

Comment: When using bootstrap you should randomly draw with replacement $N$ values out of sample of size $N$. Your procedure is **not** bootstrap.

Comment: Hi  @mdewey My data set contains each day from Jan 2010 - Apr 2016. This contains 390 attack days and 1967 days non-attack days. I want to randomly select non-attack days so the proportion of attack to non-attack days are equal, to test for differences in climatic variable on attack and any given non-attack days.

Comment: This was my code for the bootstrap @Tim, I did use it to randomly select 390 non-attack days and then used the sapply function to run it 1000 times. Sorry for mixing things up in my original post.                                                             `bootstrap <- function(i, EV, x=390){
  samp <- EV[sample(nrow(EV),nrow(EV), replace=TRUE),]
  dat <- rbind(Attack, samp)
  mod <- glm(Incident.1 ~ New.moon + TMIN + 0, data = dat, family = "binomial")
  cf <- coef(mod)[1:4]
  t <- cf / sqrt(diag(vcov(mod))[1:4])
  c(t, cf)
}
res <- sapply(1:1000, bootstrap, EV)`

Comment: There seems to be no reason to not use all the non-attack days which would gain you improved precision and avoid all this extra work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key question is "*is there any simple way to test and report the significance of my 1000 GLMs, and all the 1000 t values and coefficient distributions for my variables?*"

What you want to report is the distribution of the estimated parameters and confidence intervals.

Example:

I went ahead and generated some data, and a simple t-test is performed. Say, I'm REALLY interested in seeing what the t-statistics look like. 
Given that there is a significant difference between the sample sizes, and you want to comparable sample sizes, you can sample n (400 in my example) from each group with replacement, 
as long as you boost the number of simulations. Anything above 10^4 is fine, but I use 10^5.

```
s1 <- rnorm(n = 400, mean = 3, sd = 2) ## I'll assume there's a higher rate here
s2 <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 2, sd = 2)


t_stats <- numeric(length = 10^5)

for(i in 1:10^5){
  boot_s1 <- s1[sample(x = 1:400, size = 400, replace = TRUE)]
  boot_s2 <- s2[sample(x = 1:1000, size = 400, replace = TRUE)]
  temp <- t.test(x = boot_s1, y = boot_s2, var.equal = TRUE)
  t_stats[i] <- temp$statistic
}
```

After producing my bootstrapped samples, I can perform a statistical test.

```
qt(p = 0.95, df = 399, lower.tail = TRUE)
## null hypothesis: 95% of bootstrapped t-statistics are not beyond 1.648682

summary(t_stats)
```

From a summary, we see that 100% of above 1.65, so you can iterate that in your report or whatevs.

Next, visualize the distribution

```
hist(x = t_stats, breaks = "scott", 
     probability = TRUE, main = "Bootstrapped t-Statistics", 
     xlim = c(-1, 15), xlab = "t-Statistics")
abline(v = 1.648682, lty = 2, col = 2)
```

And include the confidence intervals of your statistics. I'm lazy, so I use the quantiles.

```
## boot CI
quantile(x = t_stats, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
```

That's pretty much it. The rest of the job is for you to provide some context as to what the analysis is showing with respect to your data.

Here's a reference for further reading/examples: http://www.statoo.com/en/publications/bootstrap_scgn_v131.pdf

Hope this helps